# writing pandas df to file using variable as file name

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write pandas df to an output file with:

```
outFileName="myfile_" + gene_name #gene_name gets a new value from argparse 

df.to_csv('%.csv' %outFileName, sep=',', index=False)
```

the error I am getting::

```
TypeError: %c requires int or char
```

I tried

```
outFileName=str("myfile_" + gene_name)
```

and got the same error. Am I missing something? I can save the df if I do not use variable as outputfile name but I need to have the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `to_csv`:

```
df.to_csv(outFileName+".csv", sep=',', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `format` for new name for file:

```
df.to_csv('myfile_{}.csv'.format(gene_name), sep=',', index=False)
```

Or if use python 3.5+ is possible use `f-string`s:

```
df.to_csv(f'myfile_{gene_name}.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = x
nameFile = name +'.csv'

with open(nameFile, "a") as a_file:
    a_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes